# How do I parse a specific child of xml output using simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I wish to parse this XML output, but only fetch the value for the "doi" record (e.g. 10.1038/onc.2012.390)

```
<ArticleIdList>
  <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">22986524</ArticleId>
  <ArticleId IdType="pii">onc2012390</ArticleId>
  <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1038/onc.2012.390</ArticleId>
</ArticleIdList>
```

Can some advise me how to accomplish this?
I've used

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($query) or die("Error, feed not loading");
```

to create the object, but could not figure out the right syntax to move fw..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `SimpleXMLElement::xpath ( string $path )` function:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file($query) or die("Error, feed not loading");
$article_doi = (string) $xml->xpath('//ArticleId[@IdType="doi"]')[0];

print_r($article_doi);
```

The output:

```
10.1038/onc.2012.390
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php